# How to save a SQL Server Maintenance Plan within a Visual Studio Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools

Having created a SQL Server maintenance plan in a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance, how can I import the definitions into a Visual Studio 2013 SSDT database project?

I don't mind using pre- and post-deployment scripts if that helps but I want it to be in a database project and to be able to build the project in VS and then to be able to deploy either a new instance of the plan, or to be able to synchronize an existing plan instance with the definitions in the database project. Also, drop and re-create is entirely acceptable.

Does anyone else already know how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all maintenance plans are not supported by SSDT.

You can export it manually as an xml template file and then try to write some sql/batch post deploy scripts to deploy it.
You can find general instruction here (read comments also): https://robertbigec.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/automating-deployment-of-sql-server-maintenance-plans/

One note: The exported xml template contains some specific values such as server name or path to backup/log file locations. You might want to write custom script to get these values from target machine and replace it in the xml file.

Comment: how do I determine the GUID for the main plan as required in the linked solution ?

Comment: Read all coments under the article. Replace GUID with this: It is needed to replace all zeros fake ids with real id taken from dtsx package.
DTS:refId=”Package\Reporting Task for subplan-{0B0E2412-2662-40EE-B7EF-695577C1C160\}”

Comment: that's not the GUID for the main plan. That's for the "subplan". Though I think I got what I was looking for from the msdb sysssispackages table. will update later if it works.